# MySQL Pool Errors

Tags: mysql, node.js

I currently have several Node.js applications utilizing a MySQL pool with a connection limit of 100. It seems that when the application runs for more than a day, queries start throwing the following error:

```
Error: Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error.
    at Protocol._validateEnqueue (/root/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:212:16)
    at Protocol._enqueue (/root/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:138:13)
    at PoolConnection.query (/root/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:198:25)
    at execute (/root/app/database/database2.js:39:9)
    at /root/app/commands/origin.js:164:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.checkExisting (/root/app/commands/origin.js:163:28)
    at Object.event (/root/app/commands/origin.js:126:32)
    at Object.init (/root/app/commands/origin.js:52:14)
    at Client.event (/root/app/events/interaction.js:86:18) {
  code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR',
  fatal: false
}
```

I've done my research, and everywhere I look, I see "Use a pool," the problem is I am using a pool. And I make sure that the connection is released back to the pool after the query is done.

Is there some method to detect fatal errors, and with that, I can restart the connection?
Is there anything else that I can look into to see what is causing this issue?

Here is my current database setup

```js
//database.js file

let mysql = require(`mysql`);
let cred = require(`../config/config.json`)[`database`];

exports.con = {
    name: `con`,
    init: async function(){     
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {   
            let pool = mysql.createPool(this.serverDetails);
                pool.getConnection((error, con) => {
                    if(error){
                        reject();
                    }else{
                        resolve(con);
                    }
                });
        }).catch(e => console.log(e));
    },
    serverDetails: {
        connectionLimit: 100,
        host     : cred[`host`],
        user     : cred[`user`],
        password : cred[`pass`],
        database : cred[`database`],
    },
};

exports.query = {
    bind: c => con = c,
    execute: (statement, details, callback) => {
        if(details){
            con.query(statement, details, function(error, results, fields){
                con.release();
                callback(error, results, fields);
            });
        }else{
            con.query(statement, function(error, results, fields){
                con.release();
                callback(error, results, fields);
            });
        }
    },
};
```

A sample query just incase that's needed

```js
await new Promise(async (resolve) => query(`INSERT INTO \`tableName\` SET ${newString} ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ${newString}`, (e, r, f) => resolve(e ? console.log(e) : 0))).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Comment: At quick glance this approach seems like an unnecessary complication. `query` is a feature of the module, so not sure why you'd need to duplicate that. Share additional context if it's important to your project. The first potential issue I see in what you've shared is your direct management of the connection. When using the module's `pool` feature you don't also need to manage connections with `con.release()`, they are managed by the module. See this example and feel free to share more specifics of your use case. https://github.com/dusthaines/mysqljs_setup_snippet/blob/master/app.js

Comment: So, the `con.release()` I just recently added as I was worried that it wasn't releasing it as it should. I know now that this is no longer the case, I just haven't removed it from the code yet, but originally that line wasn't there. As for `query` it was done more so to avoid having to put `con.query` everywhere when I could write a function called query that would take the information and transfer it to a `con.query` statement written one time rather than 800 plus times in the entire application, so it was in effort to keep the size of the application as small as possible.

Comment: And just to double check: if you run a query outside of this module using the standard setup like the example I linked, does it work? `PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR` can sometimes be the result of an authentication/permissions issue. If you are using an instance (or config) of MySQL that does not have `mysql_native_password` enabled and you're trying to connect as `root` for example. Or if `hosts` and `permissions` have not been properly defined for the user/pass you're trying to connect with?

Comment: So I don't have that but that just made me wanna ask this, would 3-4 applications using the same credentials (all accessing different databases on the same server) cause an issue?

Comment: And to answer you question yes, the entire structure of the application is very modular. The database information is only in the one file and returned to become part of an object that is passed around were needed. Been running fine for over 2 years but as of the last like 6 months or so its been throwing these errors

Comment: Multiple applications using the same credentials will not cause an issue (though not best practice in some scenarios). When the problem began 6 months ago: did everything stop working and has never worked since that time - or does it work some days/times and then not work others?

Comment: Some days and then not others